# In bash, how to expand the !$ while typing the command line?

Tags: bash, bash-completion

Is there a way to expand the `!$` in command line while interactively editing the command inside shell?

For example, while I am typing `ls !$`, I press some button and then I see what is the value of `!$`.

Comment: Can you some more details like what do you mean by `resolve the !$`? Do you want it to expand?

Comment: yes I want it to expand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you want this sequence to be treated literally, without any expansion? You may quote it with apostrophes: `'!$'`

**UPDATE** If you want to expand it before executing, you may use <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-E</kbd>, but beware that it would perform "word expansion" as well, so `!$ "single argument"` would be expanded to `expanded_string single argument` (no quotes => two arguments).

You may also use <kbd>Alt-_</kbd> (works in both emacs and vi modes), or <kbd>Alt-.</kbd> (works only in emacs mode) to just insert the last argument of the previous command directly, without any expansion.

Comment: No. I want to see the value of `!$` while typing the command.

Comment: Great. Ctrl-Al-E works in emacs editing mode. Do you know a similar magic key in vi editing mode?

Comment: @YehonathanSharvit Why do you want to use !$ at all? You may just use `Alt-.` (or `Esc` `.`, as pointed by @kev) to insert the last argument of the previous command without any expansion. And this should work in both vi and emacs modes...

Comment: update: `Alt-.` works as analogue of `!$` only in emacs mode, but `Alt-_` works in both emacs and vi.

Comment: Is there an equivalent of `Alt-_` for `!!`?

Comment: AFAIK, no, there isn't. Usually you just press the `Up` button and edit your previous command as you want.

Comment: What if you want to insert the previous command into the middle of the current line? Where can I find the doc for all this stuff?

Comment: Hm... it would help if I understand why you want to insert it... but, anyway, it's probably better to ask it as a new question.

Answer (score 4):

You can simple use：

```
!$:p
```

This will print the most recently executed command's last word.

Or type <kbd>Ctrl-Alt-e</kbd> to expand `!$`

Or type <kbd>ESC</kbd><kbd>.</kbd> to get `!$`

Comment: Great. `Ctrl-Al-E` works in emacs editing mode. Do you know a similar magic key in vi editing mode?

Answer (score 1):

You type `!$` and after that you press: `Alt-^` and the `!$` is expanded immediately.

Thanks to [@Alexis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/786948/alexis) for his answer on https://stackoverflow.com/q/9360013/813665 that reveals me the power of `Alt-^`.